# how to use make::view or redirect in laravel to open up a new tab/window?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, tabs, window

I have a page with a button having ajax function.  After the button is clicked, I would like the page to return to a new page with the variable needed to pass into the page.  the variable and everything works fine but the page wouldn't go into a new page.  It wouldn't even show in the same page only in console.

What should I do to make the view / direct / redirect to show up in a new tab / window?

**EDIT**
the whole code is quite long so let me try cutting them down.

in my controller where I have a function and after function runs it easily returns this

```
return View::make('date', array('longContents' => $longStringContainAllContents));
```

in my original parent window I have a button and simple code like this which uses ajax to go into the controller with the correct routes

```
      $.ajax({
          method: "post",
          url: "/report",
          success: function(data){
          }
      });
```

in my date.blade.php I just simply have this.

```
<div class='text-block-single'>{{ $longContents  }}</div>
```

then when I click the button, the page doesn't reload.  and in console I can see the ajax is running properly and when I see the responds in console which is good and in the console where I can see the HTML which is good too.

Comment: You said "the variable and everything works fine" and then "It wouldn't even show in the same page only in console."  So, you can get the variable to display in the console but not in the web page?  Can you include some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't accomplish this with ajax because it's asynchronous call and ajax calls returns ajax responses.
So for this staff and without seeing any code , i recommend to do this in a normal request and run redirection from your controller or router.
And if you want to open a new browser tab you must do it with JavaScript without involving any ajax and send the data thought in a normal get request to your controller or routes,

Comment: I am thinking if it'll be possible when ajax is success, using the jquery inside ajax to open a new window and pass the success data into the new window

Comment: I think better and is posible but it's little bit dirty because you are passing the params directly trough JavaScript to the new window.. just use window.open('the new url params','_blank') and prepare route or controler to render it,and place it in you'r  ajax success method ...

Comment: kind of got it to work but then the page keeps on loading. I see everything needed but where the favicon is I can see the page keeps loading.  Couldn't even inspect elements. hummm

Comment: actually I kind of saw the result wrong.  A new window does pop up with the contents but I realized the new window 's url is the same as the parent.

Comment: Strange behavior, maybe is related to initiated this with ajax, why you need ajax to this staff? I mean you can generate a simple a href element with the params that the new route will need , for example <a href="/songs/rock/long" with target blank... and you pass this to your controler in routes like Route::get(songs/{param1}/{param2} and you get will get it

Comment: true. why the heck do I need ajax for this. I have been doing ajax for all my other buttons and functions. maybe it got too deep into me.  I can still use jquery to pass the POST data entered in input elements and pass them into controller to run a function to search the database then directly use the function in controller to open up a new view or something like that right?

Comment: That's i was trying to say before but it's ok because we need to experiment  by ourselves to be better!! Good luck i hope i helped!